# Can I hang two inch blinds with only one inch of available window sill overhang?

Tags: windows, blinds

I just had new windows installed in the house and they look great! It's definitely time now to put up some decent looking blinds.

I love the look of the two-inch blinds (nothing fancy - most stuff at Lowes would seem to work fine), but I only have just a little over an inch of available overhang on the windows to mount the brackets under.

I'm definitely okay with the top of the blinds sticking out some, but I'm not sure if mounting the two inch bracket on only one inch of "wall" will be stable enough. If it wont be, would a 1.5" blind work?

I'd really like to mount inside the window opening rather than above if at all possible.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have 2" blinds from Lowes, probably the same one. Our windows had enough over hang though.  If I recall, there are little metal rectangle boxes that get mounted / screwed into the top of the window, and then the the blinds slide into the little metal box to hold it in place.  These little metal brackets have numerous holes in them on both the side, and on the top.  I think there were four screw holes, one in each corner on the top, and two on the side.  If this is indeed the type of bracket your blinds come with, then you would most likely be able to get three screws in place (1 side and 2 in the top).  Then repeat that with the other side of the blind.

This should be more than sufficient to hold it in place.  I think it would look a little funny though, I would probably go with a 1.5" for looks.  But you could use a valance to cover it up and no one would even know.

Comment: Sounds like it would work to me.  Also remember that Lowes will take them back if you decide they won't fit after you look at all the parts and dry fit them to your new windows. They have an extremely liberal return policy.

Comment: unless they are the kind that they cut to length in store, then they will not let you return them.

Comment: I actually measured my overhang instead of just guessing - and it's a full 1.5 inches. I went and bought the 2" blinds, and they look great!